# Android emulator Skin for Galaxy S3

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I am going to design a android app foe galaxy s3. Where can I get emulator skin for Galaxy S3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to eclipse window -> avd manager(Android virtual device manager). there you will get different screen size emulators and you can also create own avd

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your Android Virtual Device Manager with your custom settings.

There's how ;)

[image: AVD Manager - New Device]

You have to find S3 specifications and configure it with them.

Answer (score 0):

Even S3 is not on the list, you can find the latest Galaxy models's skins on [Samsung Developers](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/list.do?pi=1&ps=10&pb=Y&ct=CT350000&sc=). They just re-started providing their emulator skins, so I guess S3 will be uploaded soon as well.